# Compare two columns with two columns from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two similar tables, A and B.

```
Table1
|  start  |  end  |  length  |
|---------+-------+----------|
|    1    |   2   |    5.5   |
|    5    |   3   |    4.6   |
|    4    |   8   |    8.2   |
|    1    |   5   |    1.4   |
|----------------------------|

Table2
|  start  |  end  | 
|---------+-------+
|    2    |   1   |
|    5    |   3   |
|    4    |   8   |
|    3    |   1   |
|-----------------|
```

I want to select the lengths from Table1 by comparing the start and end values from Table2. In this example I would want it to select 4.6 and 8.2 (which I would later store in a variable).

My attempt so far is...(a dynamic query within a DO block)

```
        FOR tableIteration IN SELECT start FROM Table2
        LOOP
            query  := 'SELECT length '
            || 'FROM Table1 '
            || 'WHERE start IN (SELECT start FROM Table2) ' 
            || 'AND end IN (SELECT end FROM Table2) ';

            EXECUTE query INTO lengthVariable;
```

All help is appreciated.

Windows, PostgreSQL V14.2

Comment: Why do you need a dynamic query and any sort of block? This is a simple JOIN operation.

Comment: In table2, looks like the sample values are reversed in the row `2,1` instead of `1,2`. As for the question, you shouldn't need a dynamic query, just a JOIN between the tables on the two columns

Comment: The reverse sample is on purpose. I think I was confused on what the JOIN ON condition would be but I'll do that now. Thanks

Comment: What is the point of table 2? It adds no apprent value

Comment: @PaulMaxwell In the task you would be given Table2 and you need to retrieve the lengths for each row using Table1 which has the lengths for all combinations of start and end values. It doesn't really hold any value other than for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason for dynamic SQL or a DO block. This can be solved with a simple IN condition that brings `start` and `end` into the same order:

```
select *
from table1
where (least("start", "end"), 
       greatest("start", "end")) IN (select least("start", "end"), 
                                           greatest("start", "end")
                                    from table2)
```